# Sweet! Dream! Another hyper-modern art piece

Tags: cipher, visual

This puzzle belongs to the puzzle series: [hyper-modern art](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=hyper-modern%20is%3Aquestion)

---

After cracking the door code of the last room, the two friends in the gallery of hyper-modern art are moving on to the next room.

*"Oh, look at this! This image is lifting my mood quite a bit after this monochrome depression lately."*

"Yes, but I don't quite know why it's making me thirsty just to look at it."

*"Hmm, I can see what you mean. It also looks somehow familiar... What is the picture called, anyway?"*

"`Sweet Dream` - quite fitting, I'd say."

*"I agree. But now you'll soon tell me that there is more to that than meets the eye on first sight, right?"*

"Of course! Would it be hyper-modern art otherwise? As with a lot of modern art, the picture hides a message to the public."

*"Really? A political statement hidden in art? Maybe I can see through it..."*

"Not so sure if it is political, but it is clearly a statement. A wish. A dream, if you will."

---

[image: Sweet & Marvellous!]
[Full resolution image, 1.3Mb, 4000 x 3000 pixels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFOgr.jpg)

---

> The goal of this puzzle is to derive the message coded into it. This message consists of 3 words and is in English. It is hidden in the picture and not in the digital content.

You could print the picture and solve the puzzle from the printed picture. The link beneath the image leads to a full-resolution version, which might be recommended for solving this puzzle.

> Additionally to the actual message, there are also various hints 'hidden' in the image. Bonus for finding them all!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The pattern of candy and blank spaces

> matches the word lengths of Martin Luther King's "I Have A Dream" speech, starting at the line "I have a dream that one day this nation will rise up...." This is clued by the image at the bottom of a dark-colored chocolate square delivering a speech to a mixed group of light and dark squares. The orator is crowned as a "king", and the candy images come from the game Candy Crush, which was developed by the company King.

At the bottom

> the light and dark squares encode the word `ORIGINAL` using a Bacon code, while their shadows encode `ELEMENTS` (noticed by @Will).

This suggests that we find

> the candies with shape/color combinations that match the original ones in the game Candy Crush. If we superimpose MLK's speech on the candies, the letters in those spots spell out `CHOCOLATE FOR EVERYONE`, which is the message. The whole image was too large to upload, so here's a section of four lines near the middle: [image: 1]]

Comment: Using the same Baconian cipher on the shadows instead of colors encodes the word `ELEMENTS`

Comment: I immediately thought of BaconIan Cipher in the candies but was not reading the A'a and B'a in the right order. Even knowing the plaintext it took me longer than I care to admit to see it.

Comment: Congrats man! Oh dear, it obviously took me longer to build this than you to solve it. And there I thought it might be too obscure... Anyway, there is still a big clue to be 'discovered' in the puzzle for those who care. It's non Baconian and it is in the "big" sections of sweets.